# Reflection of class<T>.method

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

this is a tricky one for me...
First I'll try to explain my scenario, after that it will become the question, be patience... :-)
I'm developing a kind of compiler, so I have a common interface:

```
interface Command
{
    bool IsValid { get; }
    // ... another properties
}
```

And a base class:

```
class CommandBase<T>: Command where T : CommandBase<T>, new()
{
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
    // ... another properties

    public static Command Create<T>()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

With this layout, it becomes easy to create new command, just creating derivated classes like this:

```
class Command1 : CommandBase<Command1> { }
class Command2 : CommandBase<Command2> { }
... etc
```

I have a "Interpreter" class where I have an array like this:

```
CommandsCache = new Func<Command>[]
{
    Command1.Create,
    Command2.Create
}
```

Using this array, is easy to find which commands fits better using LINQ:

```
var command = CommandsCache
    .Where(p => /* some checks */)
    .FirstOrDefault(p => p.IsValid);
```

This way I just ripoff a lot of check codes.

Now it comes my question: How can I do to not need to update my array everytime I create a new "command"?

I just come this far:

```
var commands = typeof(Command)
    .Assembly
    .GetTypes()
    .Where(p => p.IsClass)
    .Where(p => p.BaseType != null && p.BaseType.Name.StartsWith("CommandBase"));
```

Fine, I got all types that IS a "CommandBase" derivated.
But how to invoke the "Create" saying that "T" is one of "commands"?

Comment: Why not you use `Activator.CreateInstance` to create instance instead ?

Comment: Add this to your linq query: `.Select(t => Activator.CreateInstance(t)).Cast<Command>()`

Comment: With a little ajust in my logic, I can use your suggestion @codemonkey, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using comments from you guys, I finished using this:

```
CommandsCache = typeof(Command)
    .Assembly
    .GetTypes()
    .Where(p => p.IsClass)
    .Where(p => p.BaseType != null && p.BaseType.Name.StartsWith("CommandBase"))
    .Select(Activator.CreateInstance)
    .Cast<Command>()
    .ToArray();
```

And my base class don't need the < T > "appendice" anymore... :-)
Thank you all!

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why you declares a static Create method. You can always use `Activator.CreateInstance` to create a new instance from `Type`.

I've a alternative to do what exactly you wants

```
var commands = typeof(Command)
    .Assembly
    .GetTypes()
    .Where(p => p.IsClass)
    .Where(p => p.BaseType != null && p.BaseType.Name.StartsWith("CommandBase"));


var CommandsCache = new List<Command>();

foreach (var c in commands)
{
    CommandsCache.Add((Command)Activator.CreateInstance(c));
}
```

Comment: Besides your right answer, I still prefer a "Linq" solution, thank you!